# import bdd from phpmyadmin in local to a web server in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I build a website in local using wordpress.org using a template, then I exported my bdd and my content using filezilla and imported it inside my web hoster (1&1), everything is working but the website now looks like the template with no modification..

So everyhting that I made in local is not working...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you uploaded the content but didnt import the local database to the live server. Did you do that? Once you import the database you will need to run a plugin such as https://wordpress.org/plugins/go-live-update-urls/ to change the localhost urls to the live urls.

Comment: thanks for answering! Yes I did but manually... so I will try your solution, maybe I forgot something when I change the localhost to live urls...